# Returning JSON string from 3rd party API in ASP.Net MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm wrapping a third-party API in a controller (due to security hoops we have to jump through) and the API returns a JSON string.

I do some minor changes to the JSON string and want to return that string.

I don't see a way to do that with a JSONResult, as it requires an object, and returning JSON string is sent back as a string.

Am I stuck with using something like a ContentResult?

JSONLint.com says the modified JSON is valid. It starts with...

```
[{"Acknowledgment Start Date":null,"Additional Location Details":null,"Area Code":null,"Assign To Vendor":"No",...
```

If I use the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert(), it does this to my JSON string...

```
[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],...
```

If I use JavaScriptSerializer, I get this again...

```
[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],...
```

I suspect part of the problem is the null values in the JSON string.

Is there another solution? Are there issues with using a ContentResult that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Can you show us your code?  How are you making changes to the JSON string?  Are you using JObjects or a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer inspection, I had a couple of realizations.

The first being that the outputted JSON isn't valid because the quoted identifiers include spaces and colons. For example, this one from above.

```
... ,"Additional Location Details":null, ...
```

While I suspect this is the root of problems, I don't have the time to write a parser to make it proper JSON.

I will come back and write a tool to properly clean up the mess at some point, but right now I have another approach I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert()` **serializes** an object, it doesn't **parse** (AKA deserialize) it. What you're doing when you call `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert(jsonString)` is you're saying "serialize this JSON string to JSON". So, you get a funky result.

You could instead **parse** the JSON, then make your modifications, then **serialize** it again. For example:

```
var myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.DeserializeObject<POCOClass>(jsonString);
myObject.Whatever = "123";
//... etc.
```

This of course after defining your POCO class like such:

```
public class POCOClass {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Acknowledgment Start Date")]
    public string AcknowledgmentStartDate { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then when you're done, serialize it back:

```
jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert(myObject) // or Newtonsoft.Json.SerializeObject(myObject)
```

Comment: Alternatively, if they want to use a `JsonResult` return type, they can also serialize the object with `Json(myObject)` (though it might require the JsonRequestBehavior parameter as well).

Comment: Ultimately, it strikes me as redundant to get a JSON string and deserialize it so it can be represented as a string. That seems like a lot of unnecessary work.